# Change desktop application to client server based

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, client-server, mdf

We have developed a VB.NET application with SQL Server as the back end.

Currently, the `.mdf` file is deployed along with the other files required.

Installation of the application is done and the database file (`.mdf`) is being placed and used from the local system. The application runs well in the local system.

Now the user needs the application to run in a multi-user system (server and client). As we know, to run the application in client system, the `.mdf` should be attached to the SQL Server. Attaching the `.mdf` to the server should be done programmatically and SQL Server Management Studio should not be used.

How can this be done?

- OS: Windows 7
- Front End: VB.NET
- Back End: SQL Server Express Instance

Comment: did u mean automatically?? (or grammatically)

Comment: do u have access to executing a stored procedure.?. I dnt know .net . so just asking

Comment: @jithin I think yes!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the database using known approaches. [like this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301075)

execute `CREATE DATABASE` command with appropriate parameters. [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx)

your final code should be something like this in C#

```
var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ....
conn.Open();
var command = SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE DBName ON ( FILENAME = '" + @"C:\DBName.mdf" + "' ), ( FILENAME = '" + @"C:\DBName_log.ldf" + "' ) FOR ATTACH", conn);
com.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: it looks a bit helpful.
But what will be the connection string?
And how do I check if the database is already existing?

Comment: LOL. I used "Data Source=.\SQLExpress; INITIAL CATALOG=master; uid=; pwd=;" as connection string.
I get error "Login failed for user".

Comment: Unable to open the physical file "D:\VS\CKEY BILL\CKEY BILL\CKEY BILL\bin\Debug\Data\STORAGE.MDF". Operating system error 5: "5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)"

Comment: Query Used : 
query.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE BILLSTORAGE ON(FILENAME='" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Data\STORAGE.MDF'),(FILENAME='" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Data\STORAGE_Log.LDF') FOR ATTACH"

Comment: you should ask this in new question

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this as a direct answer to your question, but this information may help you.

See the below case.
I need to attach a DB `AdventureWorks2012` to server and the `mdf` file is saved at location `D:\BI Developments\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf`

I can attain this with the below `TSQL`.

```
sp_attach_single_file_db 
@dbname='AdventureWorks2012',
@physname='D:\BI Developments\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf'
```

So, if you are able to can an SP with a similar script from your application, you may be able to add the `mdf` file.